# How to use Coroutines with Retrofit2?

Tags: api, kotlin, android-recyclerview, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I am fetching data from an api to display in a RecycerView using Retrofit2 and Kotlin Coroutines. I have just started learning Retrofit and Coroutines and at the moment the data is not displaying and I'm not sure how to solve  it! I think the issue may be with the Coroutines code. Please can someone give me some help?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var recyclerView: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rockets_list)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = RecyclerAdapter(List<RocketData>())


        CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
            val response = ApiInterface.getApi().getRockets()
            Log.i("code",response.toString())
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                try {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        recyclerView.adapter
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Error ${response.code()}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    }
                } catch (e: HttpException) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Exception ${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

```
interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("rockets")
    suspend fun getRockets(): Response<List<RocketData>>

    companion object {

        fun getApi(): ApiInterface = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(ApiInterface::class.java)
    }
}
```

Comment: As I see, you are not updating items of adapter after checking `if (response.isSuccessful)`

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing after `response.isSuccessful` check??

try setting response in Adapter then notifyDataSetChanged

```
recyclerView.adapter.items = response
recyclerView.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Answer (score 0):

your Retrofit and Coroutine implementation works fine,
you just didn't update your adapter list after successful response check

```
if (response.isSuccessful) {
    recyclerView.adapter.list = response.body
    recyclerView.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

also you can't display `Toast` from within a Coroutine, wrap it inside `runOnUiThread{}`